# How do I make HTML5 game obstacles?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a HTML5 game without any frameworks. My player can go up, down, left and right, but it can even walk through obstacles. I edited some things and now it can't get through obstacles, but when my player walks against it, the player can't get back. He gets stuck.

All fixed objects are stored in `this.fixed` and all sprites are stored in `this.sprite`. Structure of `this.sprite` is:

- 0 = x
- 1 = y
- 2 = w
- 3 = h
- Four and five doesn't matter.

**This is the code:**

```
moveSprite:function( name, x, y, w, h, type)
    {   
        w = typeof w !== 'undefined' ? w : this.sprite[name][2];
        h = typeof h !== 'undefined' ? h : this.sprite[name][3];
        type = typeof type !== 'undefined' ? type : 'rect';

        for ( f in this.fixed )
        {
            if 
            ( 
              // X

              /* Left */ this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][0] - 3 < this.sprite[name][0] + this.sprite[name][2] && 
              /* Right */ this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][0] + this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][2]  > this.sprite[name][0] &&

              // Y

              /* Bottom */ this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][1] < this.sprite[name][1] + this.sprite[name][3] && 
              /* Top */ this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][1]  + this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][3] > this.sprite[name][1]
            )
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        if( type == 'rect' )
        {
            this.context.clearRect(this.sprite[name][0],this.sprite[name][1],this.sprite[name][2],this.sprite[name][3]);
            this.context.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
        }
        else
        {

            var path = this.sprite[name][5];
            this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
            delete this.sprite[name];

            for ( var i in this.sprite )
            {
                if( this.sprite[i][4] == 'rect' )
                {
                    this.context.fillRect(this.sprite[i][0],this.sprite[i][1],this.sprite[i][2],this.sprite[i][3]);
                }
                else if ( this.sprite[i][4] == 'image' )
                {
                    this.addImage( this.sprite[i][5], this.sprite[i][0], this.sprite[i][1], this.sprite[i][2], this.sprite[i][3] );
                }   
            }

            this.addSprite(name, x,y,w,h,'image', path);


        }

    },
```

I use the function with the name from the player sprite.

**What did I tried?**

I Google'd for collision detection, now I have collision detection, but my player gets stuck.
I also Google'd for HTML5 obstacles but I didn't found anything useful about that.

Comment: At a guess, they're stuck inside. Reposition them outside when they collide.

Comment: @EvanKnowles The player can get into from left, right, up and down in the object. How I have to know how did the player got into the object?

Comment: Do the collision detection before moving the player. If the player collides, then don't move it.

Comment: I do that, but then the player gets stuck. The for-loop is the collision detection. @EvanKnowles

Comment: What provides the x, y coordinates... I'm guessing the issue is there and that they are still being modified upon collision.

Comment: When a sprite moves, the x and y coordinates updates in the this.sprite variable (It doesn't update when it detects collision). So I get the x and y coordinates from the this.sprite variable. Or did you mean that not? @GeorgeReith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comments given, I made this:

```
moveSprite:function( name, x, y, movement, w, h, type)
    {   
        w = typeof w !== 'undefined' ? w : this.sprite[name][2];
        h = typeof h !== 'undefined' ? h : this.sprite[name][3];
        type = typeof type !== 'undefined' ? type : 'rect';

        //console.log('sdf');
        for ( f in this.fixed )
        {
            if ( this.stuck === false )
            {
                if 
                ( 
                  // X

                  /* Left */ this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][0] < this.sprite[name][0] + this.sprite[name][2] && 
                  /* Right */ this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][0] + this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][2]  > this.sprite[name][0] &&

                  // Y

                  /* Bottom */ this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][1] < this.sprite[name][1] + this.sprite[name][3] && 
                  /* Top */ this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][1]  + this.sprite[this.fixed[f]][3] > this.sprite[name][1]
                )
                {
                    this.stuck = movement;
                    return;
                }

            }
            else if ( this.stuck !== false && movement == this.stuck )
            {
                this.block = true;
                return;
            }
            if ( this.stuck !== false && this.block == true && movement != this.stuck )
            {
                this.block = false;
                this.stuck = false;
                movement = null;
                console.log(1);
            }
        }

        if( type == 'rect' )
        {
            this.context.clearRect(this.sprite[name][0],this.sprite[name][1],this.sprite[name][2],this.sprite[name][3]);
            this.context.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
        }
        else
        {

            var path = this.sprite[name][5];
            this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height);
            delete this.sprite[name];

            for ( var i in this.sprite )
            {
                if( this.sprite[i][4] == 'rect' )
                {
                    this.context.fillRect(this.sprite[i][0],this.sprite[i][1],this.sprite[i][2],this.sprite[i][3]);
                }
                else if ( this.sprite[i][4] == 'image' )
                {
                    this.addImage( this.sprite[i][5], this.sprite[i][0], this.sprite[i][1], this.sprite[i][2], this.sprite[i][3] );
                }   
            }

            this.addSprite(name, x,y,w,h,'image', path);


        }

    },
```

Now it works, thanks for your help! :)